# Relocating a Referenced File in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: svn, vb6

I'm in the process of moving files to an SVN repository from various places. Some of these are projects in Visual Basic 6.0 but I have only extremely limited experience working with the language, and I'm not sure how to go about piecing the references back together.

Opening the VB project gives an error that a file is not found (the subdirectory the file was formerly located in was just left sporadically in My Documents, obviously unacceptable). I need to change the reference to this .cls file so that I can move the file to a localized url on the SVN and then just point the VB project to that.

It seems complicated at first glance but I'm confident that there's a very simple solution I'm overlooking. If any further information would be helpful please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a .cls file or dll? Reference would be for a dll.  If its a class file then you can import it into the project from the File menu.  If it's a dll, a reference to a shared library, then it has to reside on the machine, of course if its a common windows dll there may be a newer version on the machine, in the windows folder that you can use in place of an old file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Bingo, thank you. It's a .cls as I mentioned, I hadn't even realized that meant it was a class. You can't do this from the file menu, but I figured it out: you just right click on the Project Manager and add-->Add File. Thanks. =)